# IBM Watson Conversation API DOC not present

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson, watson-conversation

On IBM Watson doc 
https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#introduction

I look the only CURL request example.
I need the Java request example

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the tests available with the SDK.

In particular look at:
https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/conversation/src/test/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationServiceIT.java#L90

Answer (score 1):

First, add the Maven dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-sdk</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Compile with Gradle: `com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.3.1`

And request the Conversation service with the [following](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/tree/develop/conversation) code:

```
ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConversationService.VERSION_DATE_2017_03_02);
service.setUsernameAndPassword("<username>", "<password>");

MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText("Hi").build();
MessageResponse response = service.message("<workspace-id>", newMessage).execute();
System.out.println(response);
//Moving from Node 1 to Node 2.

Map<String, Object> context = new HashMap<String, Object>();

// first message
MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder()
    .input(new InputData.Builder("First message").build())
    .context(context)
    .build();

MessageResponse response = service.message("<workspace-id>", newMessage).execute();

// second message
newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder()
    .input(new InputData.Builder("Second message").build())
    .context(response.getContext()) // output context from the first message
    .build();

response = service.message("<workspace-id>", newMessage).execute();

System.out.println(response);
```

See the code inside [Java SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk/blob/develop/examples/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/developer_cloud/conversation/v1/ConversationExample.java#L29) from IBM Developers.

I think you can like this Project with [Conversation and Discovery](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-with-discovery/blob/master/src/main/java/com/ibm/watson/apis/conversation_with_discovery/listener/SetupThread.java#L142) to verify others examples.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of the Watson Assistant (formerly Conversation) API reference documentation includes Java examples: https://console.bluemix.net/apidocs/assistant?language=java